# problem accessing network through terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

I am using ubuntu 10.04 and I am having trouble accessing my Internet through terminal, while I am able to access it through browser.

In terminal, if I try to ping any server with its name, like ping google.com, I am able to do that, even I can successfully used nslookup and several other network commands, but when I tried to download something, using  "wget" or install something using "gem install" or checking out some code using "svn", I got server timeout error.

Can anybody help me figure out the problem.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe the server is down ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure if a particular server is up, you can try running its address through http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/.